# Multiple Panes in Excel 2003 Spreadsheet XML

Tags: excel, spreadsheetml, xml-spreadsheet

I want to generate an excel spreadsheet with three horizontal panes.

1. Report Header
2. Report Titles
3. Report Values

So that the Titles will scroll to the top of the document and then "freeze" while the Values scroll underneath the Titles.

I have been able to setup two panes with the following Worksheet Options:

```
<FreezePanes/>
<SplitHorizontal>11</SplitHorizontal>
<TopRowBottomPane>11</TopRowBottomPane>
<ActivePane>2</ActivePane>
<Panes>
  <Pane>
    <Number>3</Number>
  </Pane>
  <Pane>
    <Number>2</Number>
  </Pane>
</Panes>
```

I'm not that experienced with Excel, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I cannot complain, at least I got a badge out of this.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news on this one Matt, but no, you can't have 3 or more horizontal or vertical panes. 2 is the max for either - but you could have two horizontal and two vertical on the same sheet.

Comment: Hm. Not sure what to make of that information but it's good to know.  Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Matt H. - Yeah, I sometimes wish there were 3 panes too. Now what would it take for me to win the bounty? :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought it was automatic with the answer.  My apologies, now awarded.